# Fail to delete a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I am just learning pointer and dynamic memory allocation with keywords `new` and `delete`.

Below is my C++ code to test my understanding.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    // Variable to be pointed to by a pointer
    cout << "Create a double variable" << endl;
    double n = 3.1415926;
    cout << "n = " << n << endl;
    cout << "&n = " << &n << endl << endl;

    // Dynamic memory allocation
    cout << "Dynamically allocate memory to a pointer" << endl;
    double * ptr = new double;
    ptr = &n;       // Error when delete ptr
    // *ptr = n;    // Can delete ptr
    cout << "ptr = " << ptr << endl;
    cout << "*ptr = " << *ptr << endl << endl;


    // Free the pointer memory
    cout << "Delete the pointer" << endl;
    delete ptr;
    cout << "Done" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When the pointer `ptr` is pointing the the address of `n` (i.e. `ptr = &n`). The console print out is as follow with error.

```
$ ./test
Create a double variable
n = 3.14159
&n = 0x7ffee304f830

Dynamically allocate memory to a pointer
ptr = 0x7ffee304f830
*ptr = 3.14159

Delete the pointer
test(2436,0x118bf05c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ffee304f830: pointer being freed was not allocated
test(2436,0x118bf05c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

But when the pointer is assigned like this: `*ptr = n`. No such error occurs. Moreover, `ptr` is pointed to the address of `0x7faa7e400630` which is not the address of `n`

My understanding is that `ptr` in both cases is a valid pointer (with a valid address). But I don't know why `delete ptr` does not work for the case of `ptr = &n`. Any help to facilitate my understanding is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `double * ptr = new double; ptr = &n;` -- This is a memory leak, as you've thrown away the pointer that `new` returned to you by overwriting `ptr`.  Also, place a `cout <<ptr;` right after the call to `new`.  That value is what you should be `delete`-ing.

Answer (score 2):

> But when the pointer is assigned like this: `*ptr = n`. No such error occurs.

When you execute `*ptr = n`, the pointer does not get deleted. It's a simple assignment operation. `ptr` points to a valid memory. Hence, assigning to `*ptr` is not a problem.

> But I don't know why delete ptr does not work for the case of `ptr = &n`

You can only `delete` what has been obtained by `new`. `&n` is not one such pointer. Executing `delete ptr` is the same as executing `delete &n`. That is not correct and is cause for undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

> But I don't know why delete ptr does not work for the case of `ptr = &n`

`n` is an automatic variable. Deleting the address of an automatic variable has undefined behaviour.

`delete` expression on any pointer other than one that was returned by (non-placement) `new` expression has undefined behaviour (except a null pointer; it is safe to delete null). That is how the language is specified. When the behaviour is undefined, the program may produce an error.

`ptr = &n` assigns over the value that had been returned by `new`. Since the value is no longer stored anywhere, it will no longer be possible `delete` it. This is called a memory leak.

> But when the pointer is assigned like this: `*ptr = n`. No such error occurs.

`*` is the indirection operator. That expression does not assign the pointer. `ptr` still points at the object in dynamic storage. It does not point to `n`. `delete` expression on a pointer **was** returned by a new-expression has well-defined behaviour. The behaviour is to destroy the object and to deallocate the memory.

This assignment sets the value of the object pointed by `ptr`. The value of that number is now the same value as `n` variable has.